# queries are not getting updated even on successful C# windows forms

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(" Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.sdf; Persist Security Info=False ;");
    connection.Open();

    MessageBox.Show("Connection successful");
    //listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("insert into malware (malwarename, threatlevel,malwaretype,kind,Description,Reg,network,developer,exportfix,date,id,signature)VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + " ' ,  ' " + listBox1.SelectedItem + " ', '" + listBox2.SelectedItem + "' , '" + listBox3.SelectedItem + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "');", connection);

    MessageBox.Show("fine till here ");
    //SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteQuery();
    //reader.Close();

    int m = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(m .ToString());
    connection.Close();
}
```

Why my queries not updated on apply when I check?

Comment: value of m is 1 which means query is passed and ok but when i check database it is empty..

Comment: Do you get any exception or error message? Also please use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) . This kind of string concatenations are open for [_SQL Injection_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Gosh - what a SQL injection just waiting to happen! You need to read up on **SQL injection** and start using **parametrized queries** to avoid it! **Right now!**

Comment: Msgbox the query. Then copy it paste in sol and run it.

Answer (score 3):

*Well*, you didn't tell us do you have an error or not, here is the right way to do it.

First, you should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Second, you should dispose your connection with [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) keyword.

> To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection
>   inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment.
>   Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the
>   code exits the block.

Third, `DATE` could be [`reserved keyword`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in future releases of SQL Server. You might need to use it with square brackets like `[DATE]`. As a general recomendation, don't use reserved keywords for your identifiers and object names in your database.

Here is an example;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.sdf; Persist Security Info=False;"))
    {
      SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("insert into malware (malwarename, threatlevel,malwaretype,kind,Description,Reg,network,developer,exportfix,[date],id,signature)
                               VALUES(@malwarename, @threatlevel, @malwaretype, @kind, @Description, @Reg, @network, @developer, @exportfix, @date, @id, @signature)", 
                               connection);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@malwarename", textBox1.Text);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@threatlevel", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@malwaretype", listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kind", listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString());
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descriptione", textBox2.Text);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reg", textBox3.Text);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@network", textBox4.Text);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@developer", textBox5.Text);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exportfix", textBox8.Text);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox6.Text);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue(" @signature", textBox7.Text);
      connection.Open();
      int m = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());
      connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your checked database is your updated database ?
And then, Maybe you can put code statement of try-catch-finally ,check your app maybe throw some exception has occurred, try it!